# C# log4net TextWriterAppender is not working with TextBox

Tags: c#, log4net

C# project 1: Library

```
public class TaskDummy : IPlannedTask {

    private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TaskDummy));

    // implements interface
    public void run(System.IO.TextWriter x, object paramIn=null) {
        initLog(x);
        String msg = "Dummy task is running";
        // direct & indirect call of TextWriter::WriteLine
        x.WriteLine(msg);
        log.Info(msg);
    }

    private void initLog(System.IO.TextWriter x) {
        log4net.Appender = new log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender();
        textAppender.Writer = x;
        // ...
    }

}
```

results in TaskDummy.dll. log4net is configured with a TextWriterAppender at runtime.

C# project 2: Console app in same solution with reference on project 1.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TaskDummy t = new TaskDummy();
        t.run(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

This will print

```
    Dummy task is running
    INFO - Dummy task is running
```

as exspected (direct & indirect call). The TextWriter is the one from console output.

C# project 3: Windows Forms

```
public class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter {

    protected TextBox box;

    public TextBoxWriter(TextBox box) {
        this.box = box; 
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }

    delegate void WriteLineCallBack(String value);

    public override void WriteLine(String value) {
        if(box.InvokeRequired) {
            WriteLineCallBack d = new WriteLineCallBack(WriteLine);
            box.Invoke(d, new object[] { value });
        } else {
            base.Write(value);
            box.AppendText(value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of TextWriter to write into Windows Forms Textbox (cross-thread). This project loads implementations of IPlannedTask (see project 1) and calls their method run():

```
// txtLog is a Textbox control
TextBoxWriter twOutput = new TextBowWriter(txtLog);

var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile("TaskDummy.dll");
Type t = DLL.getExportedTypes()[0];
dynamic d = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
((IPlannedTask)d).run(twOutput);
```

This results in only one line in textbox from the direct call of WriteLine (see project 1). The log.Info call does not work (the method TextBoxWriter::WriteLine is not even called).

=> Why does TextWriterAppender of log4net work with Console.Out but not with TextBoxWriter

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.ImmediateFlush.html     Does it make a difference if you set this to True?

Comment: If you make changes to an appender at runtime, you must call `appender.ActivateOptions()` for them to take effect.